# Limit using Sokhotski–Plemelj Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to understand how the following Limit is calculated (equation (9) in the [paper](http://sethna.lassp.cornell.edu/elastic_theory_has_zero_radius_of_convergence))

$$    \lim_{\epsilon \to +0}Z(-P+i\epsilon) =  \lim_{\epsilon \to +0}  \int_{0}^{\infty}   \mathrm{d}x \, \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}y \exp \{ -\alpha y -\beta x^2 - y(-P+i \epsilon)x    \}$$

The author says use is to be made of the Theorem
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to +0} \int \mathrm{d}x f(x)/(x+i \epsilon) = P.V. \int \mathrm{d}x f(x)/x -i \pi f(0) $$

but how to get there?
My best attempt is to integrate on the $y$ variable, obtaining

$$     \lim_{\epsilon \to +0}  \int_{0}^{\infty}   \mathrm{d}x \,  \exp \{ -\beta x^2 \}  \left[- \frac{1}{-\alpha-(-P+i \epsilon)x}   \right ]$$

To use the Theorem I need the denominator to be of the form $y+i \epsilon$, which is not as the variable of Integration is multiplied by $\epsilon$, so I am unable to proceed. I am even more puzzled because if I set $ \epsilon$ to Zero, the integral I wrote coincides with the P.V. integral reported in the paper as the P.V. contribution in the Sokhotski–Plemelj formula.

Any help please, would be most appreciated.

Comment: You are faced to a "full fledged" distribution $1/(x+i0_+) = PV(1/x)-i\pi \delta= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0+}(x/(x^2+\epsilon^2)-i\epsilon/(x^2+\epsilon^2))$; have a look first at http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105729/principal-value-of-1-x-and-few-questions-about-complex-analysis   see also the end ofhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_distribution

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had a look at what you suggested and I think I have a basic grasp of what the Plemenj formula means. I am struggling though in applying it in this concrete case, to derive the final result (equation 9 in the paper).

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/244489/2451